# Disable PDF viewer in Modern User Interface SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, pdf, modern-experience, 2019

I have been testing SharePoint 2019 and I have a question related to Modern User Interface PDF Viewer Configurations.

On my SharePoint 2019 On-Premise environment, I have Office Web Apps Configured but we don’t want to Open PDF in the Office Web-App, we want to open it in the Client Application.

In the previous SharePoint versions, I used the commands below:

• Get-SPWOPIBinding –Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false

• Did an IIS reset.

• Cleared browser Cache.

The PDF opened in Client Application for SharePoint Classic User Interface but in Modern User Interface it opens in default PDF Viewer(screenshot below). [image]

Comment: Can you activate the `Open Documents in Client Applications by Default ` feature in site collection and check ( Site collection settings > Site collection features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, in SharePoint 2019 preview release PDF viewer included and pdf files open in SharePoint without Office online.

> "SharePoint Server 2019 Public Preview can now render PDF documents on
>   the server. Users no longer need to rely on a PDF viewer client
>   application."

But this feature is not stable and it is removed from the documentation as well. I would wait for RTM release of SharePoint 2019 then try it.

Check the open item under the feedback at the end of page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-2019